# How does update counter_cache when we run raw SQL?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've got few counter caches which update when model save/update or destroy because of after hook. If I create/update or destroy record using raw SQL, how can I update counter cache automatically?

Comment: If you are bypassing the rails active record mechanisms by using raw SQL, then your callbacks will not automatically be called.  Did you mean to say "how do I update the counters *manually*"?

Comment: @Daiku I know that callbacks will not be called. I just wondering is there any way to do that automatically when SQL ran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods/reset_counters

```
# For Post with id #1 records reset the comments_count
Post.reset_counters(1, :comments)
```

> Resets one or more counter caches to their correct value using an SQL count query. This is useful when adding new counter caches, or if the counter has been corrupted or modified directly by SQL.

Comment: thats one perfect for it